# Progressing from a C Minor 9th

Tags: theory, piano, chords, harmony, chord-theory

If I am playing a C Minor 9th chord what are the next chords up that work with a C Minor 9th? Am I able to follow the C Minor scale and create a 9th from each note in the scale? A bit confused on where to go from a C Minor 9th.

Edit: [This](https://soundcloud.com/gv1uk/timmy-mallet-work-in-progress) is what I was able to come up with ... but it feels like it's lacking movement:

Comment: Context is really important here.  What key are you in?  What style of music are you playing?  What theory of harmony do you subscribe to?  Virtually any chord can follow a Cm9 -- or any other chord -- depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything above the 7th degree of a chord is considered "upper-tertian harmony" in a tertian context.  That means that extra notes are essentially just adding extra pitch-color to the chord.  Though these extra notes can absolutely be incorporated into the chord progression, they do not have to be.

How you treat the chord depends on how you want to contextualize it.  I'm not going to list things as there are an innumerable ways to contextualize anything in music.  That said, I would think about whether the chord is being used as progression or resolution, and move onward from there.

Comment: I agree with this. There aren't actually any "rules" about which chords follow what (unless you're adhering to a strict genre). You just use which chords sound good to you. The best ways to find these chords are experimenting a lot and listening closely to other people's music.

Answer (score 2):

You could always play a G7 since a Cm9 contains the notes `C - Eb - G - Bb - D` and G7 contains `G - B - D - F`. There is enough motion to make the chord have a different sound than  the Cm9, but keep enough common tones to make the motion easy between them. Other possibilities include Bb7, Fm7, ect. You can pretty much follow it up with any chord native to the to C minor. In the end, it has to sound good to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since Cm is relative to Eb major, the chords produced from it will be Ebmaj9; Fm9; Gm9; Abmaj9; Bbdom9; Cm9; Do.

Not sure whether you mean to have an answer like this, or whether you are looking for chord/s that would follow Cm9 in a sequence in a song.  Any of the above would sound fine,along with a diminished chord made from C, or G, or D - these notes contained in the Cm9 chord, so would be working in a pivotal manner i.e. any diminished chord !

Answer (score 1):

You can do is try this sequence:
Cm9(C-Eb-G-Bb-D), then Fm9(F-Ab-C-Eb-G) or Fm7(F-Ab-C-Eb) and then Gm7(G-Bb-D-F)
I simply love to play this chord pattern on any scale.
I suggest, play all these chords in a strumming manner. 
It sounds really nice to me!